# Installing my python package on MacOS gives bad marshall data error

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, setuptools, setup.py

I'm getting the below mentioned bad marshal data error when installing my own created python package on Mac OS.

```
deveshs-MacBook-Pro:mycli devesh$ sudo python setup-4.0.py install 
running install
Checking .pth file support in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/
/usr/bin/python -E -c pass
TEST PASSED: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ appears to support .pth files
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing requirements to mycli.egg-info/requires.txt
writing cftcli.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to mycli.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to mycli.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing entry points to mycli.egg-info/entry_points.txt
reading manifest file 'mycli.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'mycli.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.macosx-10.10-intel/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
copying mycli.egg-info/PKG-INFO -> build/bdist.macosx-10.10-intel/egg/EGG-INFO
copying mycli.egg-info/SOURCES.txt -> build/bdist.macosx-10.10-intel/egg/EGG-INFO
copying mycli.egg-info/dependency_links.txt -> build/bdist.macosx-10.10-intel/egg/EGG-INFO
copying mycli.egg-info/entry_points.txt -> build/bdist.macosx-10.10-intel/egg/EGG-INFO
copying mycli.egg-info/requires.txt -> build/bdist.macosx-10.10-intel/egg/EGG-INFO
copying mycli.egg-info/top_level.txt -> build/bdist.macosx-10.10-intel/egg/EGG-INFO
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup-4.0.py", line 42, in <module>
"requests==2.4.3",
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
dist.run_commands()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
cmd_obj.run()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 67, in run
self.do_egg_install()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 109, in do_egg_install
self.run_command('bdist_egg')
      File         "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
cmd_obj.run()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 208, in run
os.path.join(archive_root, 'EGG-INFO'), self.zip_safe()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 244, in zip_safe
return analyze_egg(self.bdist_dir, self.stubs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 354, in analyze_egg
safe = scan_module(egg_dir, base, name, stubs) and safe
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 391, in scan_module
code = marshal.load(f)
ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
```

I tried deleting all the *.pyc files from the setuptools directory.
Please guide how this issue can be resolved. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I thought that the issue is with the filename, which should be `setup.py` only, but it gave same error with `sudo python setup.py install` too.

A workaround I found out is to create a source-distribution first.
[see documentation here](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/sourcedist.html)

Below is the script which will work fine and put us out from the above issue.

```
cp -f setup-4.0.py setup.py
python setup.py sdist --format=zip,gztar
sudo pip install dist/mycli-4.0.tar.gz
rm setup.py
```

To uninstall: `sudo pip uninstall mycli`

Hope it will help some Mac users. Thanks.